# How can I create an automatic update on a web page based on date/time?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I am managing an internet radio station webpage and I would like to add an auto entry for the station's programming based on the day of week / time of day. For example at 8.00am on a Monday to Friday the "Now Playing" title shows "The Breakfast Show", at 10.00am it changes to "The Fred and Lucy Hour", and on a Sunday at 6.00pm it shows "The Hymn Hour"" etc. etc.

I have worked out how to get the server date and time on the webpage using PHP, and I am guessing this should somehow be linked to an SQL Database which contains all the shows and their timings, but as a complete novice on all things PHP and SQL I have no idea how to link them together (if indeed it is possible) or whether any other additional programming is necessary.

I would appreciate a steer in the right direction from someone better qualified than me.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:-
For various reasons I chose to go with the coding based on an array of Weekdays / Times/ Shows and initially it seemed to work well until I realised that even though I set the "$hour = date('H:i');", the code seemed to ignore the minutes in the array list. Following further advice (see comments below) I have overcome the problem and the code immediately below has been updated and is now in use. (Note I have shown a shortened test version of the array which can be amended and added to as required.):-

```
$shows = [
    3 => [
        '20:00' => 'Test result A',
        '20:30' => 'Test result B',
        '21:00' => 'Test result C',
        '21:10' => 'Test result D',
        '21:30' => 'Test result E'
    ],
];

$weekday = date('N');
$hour = date('H:i');
$now_plaing = 'Default show';
    
foreach($shows[$weekday] as $h=>$show) {
    if ($h <= $hour) $now_plaing = $show;

printf("On Air Now: %s", $now_plaing);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simple code like this:

```
<?php
$weekday = date('N');
$hour = date('H');
if (1 <= $weekday && $weekday <= 5) {
    // Monday to friday
    if ( $hour > 8 ) {
        $now_plaing = 'The Breakfast Show';
    } elseif ( $hour >=10 ) {
        $now_plaing = 'The Fred and Lucy Hour';
    } else {
        $now_plaing = 'Some good show';
    }
} elseif ($weekday == 7) {
    // Sunday
    
    if ( $hour > 6 ) {
        $now_plaing = 'The Hymn Hour';
    } else {
        $now_plaing = 'Sunday good show';
    }
}

printf("Now Playing: %s", $now_plaing);
```

[Test PHP code online](https://phpize.online/?phpses=dbfd168dafe7b426c6866d5446a50c83&sqlses=&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57)

Another way is build shows array (or get it from Data Base) and use another code:

```
<?php

$shows = [
    1 => [
        0 => 'Morning show',
        8 => 'The Breakfast Show',
        10 => 'The Fred and Lucy Hour'
    ],
    /*** each day shows array ***/
    7 => [
        0 => 'Sunday good show',
        6 => 'The Hymn Hour'
    ]
];

$weekday = date('N');
$hour = date('H');
$now_plaing = 'Default show';
    
foreach($shows[$weekday] as $h=>$show) {
    if ($h <= $hour) $now_plaing = $show;
}

printf("Now Playing: %s", $now_plaing);
```

[PHP sandbox](https://phpize.online/?phpses=fbab8d591f719fa7416760ef6048fffc&sqlses=&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57)

Using DB:

```
<?php

$weekday = date('N');
$hour = date('H:i');
$now_plaing = 'Default show';
    
$query = "SELECT show_name FROM shows WHERE weekday = ? AND start_at <= ? ORDER BY start_at DESC LIMIT 1;";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute([$weekday, $hour]);

$show = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

printf("Now at %s playing: %s", $hour, $show['show_name']);
```

[SQL + PHP test](https://phpize.online/?phpses=1dd3a5dd03517db656f8111e84459934&sqlses=5cc522a46c6d6644a8355f539f737f85&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57)

Comment: Please see my update. The code works for hours but seems to ignore minutes. How can I correct this?

Comment: You should to use string indexes in your array for example '21:30' instead 21.30 : https://phpize.online/?phpses=7a0fcb55bbf7ba6409a05c1a93924c74&sqlses=null&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57

Comment: I have done as you suggest and the code is working as required now. I have updated my original post to show the full working code in the hope that it might be helpful to someone else. Apparently I should not say Thank You Slava but can confirm you advice has been most helpful.